# DISM capture and apply WIN10 image failure. Need guidance

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, uefi, imaging

I've hit quite a snag here.

I booted from WINPE5.1 and ran DISM and captured a Windows 10 golden instance image and the UEFI System Partition (what I traditionally knew as system partition) saved to external hard drive. It seems that I did not image the Microsost Reserved Partition (MSR) and I proceeded to run diskpart and clean disk 0.

I then applied Windows .WIM to primary parititon created in disk part, and the system .WIM to the primary partition labed System. I then set this system partition as active.

Windows will not boot. What steps am I missing? In reading these articles it seems that I should have included the MSR partition and set the primary partition I created as a GPT partition--something I did not do.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765951(v=ws.10).aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304353(v=ws.10).aspx

Obviously, I'm missing a lot of steps given that imaging for UEFI system is not as straight-forward as for MBR. I still have a good windows .WIM file (I think). Is there a way I can create the necessary system and MSR partition so I can boot to windows from my .WIM?

In general, how should I go about imaging and deploying a Windows 10 image in UEFI system? Instructions on the internet are all over the place. Switching to legacy BIOS to boot is not an option. It also seems like a lot of work just to use .WIMs (file based) over sector based imaging. There has to be a benefit to doing it this way, right?

Please help.

Comment: "Obviously, I'm missing a lot of steps given that imaging for UEFI system is not as straight-forward as for MBR." - There is literally no difference.  Instead of an 100 MB partition you create a 350 MB EFI partition.

Comment: But don't I have to make the new primary partition that Windows image will be applied to a GPT partition? And what about the MSR partition that I left out?

Comment: You will need to include it.  .WIM is useful when you script the process.  You can automate the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to sector-based images, Windows images (.wim) have several advantages, including deduplication, creating multiple images in one file using image indexes, and built-in support for image servicing (inserting files, packages, updates, etc.) using DISM.

Microsoft provides a detailed Windows deployment guide using Windows images available at [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-system-and-recovery-partitions). I will summarize the main steps below.

- First, ensure that the target disk has a GPT partition table. You can use Diskpart to clean the disk and partition it as GPT. All partitions on the disk will be destroyed. You can refer to the [Windows partitioning guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions) for details. The guide uses these commands to create a GPT partition table:

  ```
  list disk
  select disk 0
  clean
  convert gpt
  ```

  Replace "0" with the actual number of the target disk obtained in the `list disk` command.
- Next, prepare EFI, MSR and Windows partition using Diskpart or a similar tool. The guide above assumes that we create a 100MB EFI system partition, a small MSR partition, the Windows partition, and a Recovery partition.
- After partitioning, apply your Windows image to the Windows partition. For example:

  ```
  dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:D:\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:W:\
  ```

  Replace `W:\` with the path to the Windows partition, and `D:\install.wim` with the path of your Windows image file. Files included in the image will be unpacked to the specified partition.
- Install boot files into the system partition using the BCDBoot tool included in the new Windows installation. For example:

  ```
  W:\Windows\System32\bcdboot W:\Windows /s S:
  ```

  Replace `W:\Windows` with the path to the new Windows installation, and `S:\` with the path to the EFI system partition.
- Finally, install the Windows recovery image to the recovery partition.

  ```
  md R:\Recovery\WindowsRE
  copy W:\Windows\System32\Recovery\winre.wim R:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winre.wim
  W:\Windows\System32\reagentc /setreimage /path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /target W:\Windows
  ```

  Replace `R:\` with the path to the recovery partition.

---

Alternately, Microsoft Deployment Toolkit contains all the necessary tools for creating, customizing and deploying Windows installations. If you regularly deploy Windows, I highly recommend the tool.