# Using DISM to deploy a captured image to an arbitrary partition on another disk

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, uefi

(continued as a hopefully more concise and focused rewrite of [my older post](https://superuser.com/questions/1523074/cloning-moving-windows-partition-to-an-arbitrary-destination-on-another-disk))

Given an existing installation of Windows 10 on a disk, is it possible to use the DISM tool to capture it and apply it to an **arbitrary** NTFS partition on another disk? That is to say, does the answer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1251997/dism-capture-and-apply-win10-image-failure-need-guidance) (capture, apply, `bcdboot`, profit) suffice in this situation? Capturing and applying images is the obvious purpose of DISM, but I cannot find any answers on whether such images can be deployed to *arbitrary* locations.

Assume that the target machines are identical in terms of hardware (actually, one of them is the same machine itself, just using a different disk), and that all of the target partitions have the same size as the source installation, but not necessarily the same sector offset.

Comment: DISM can only be used to create an images of an entire partition.  Image of a partition is created, image is applied to a partition of the same size, partition will be identical to that of the source partition.

Comment: That is my intent. I only want to capture my Windows partition to be [re]deployed elsewhere.

Comment: The use of DISM can be scripted.  I don’t understand your question

Comment: Given an existing Windows 10 installation on, say, `/dev/sda42`, and a blank NTFS partition on `/dev/sdb23` (of the same size, but not block offset), can I just use DISM to capture the source image, apply it to the target partition, and `bcdboot` it to make it bootable? The intent of the question is to ask whether such WIM images can be applied to any target partition (of appropriate size).

Comment: That’s typically how these images are used.  A script creates the partitions, script applies the images to each partition, system is rebooted in order to finish the initializing the OS.

Comment: Oh, good, that's what I wanted to find out. I was planning on doing that today. I asked this question because I tried a different way of cloning, namely `ntfsclone` instead of `dism`, and that didn't work.